# Retrofit + Gson can not parse simple Map

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

I have a JSON as follows

```
{
  "1.2.3.4": "domain1.com",
  "1.2.3.5": "domain2.com"
}
```

And a model

```
public class DnsLookup {
  @Getter @Setter private Map<String, String> entry;
}
```

And retrofit query interface

```
  @GET("/dns/")
  Call<DnsLookup> getDns(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

When I make the query, I get `null` in `dns`.

```
    Call<DnsLookup> call = service.getDns(queryMap);
    Response<DnsLookup> response;
    response = call.execute();
    var dns = response.body();
```

Actually the original JSON is

```
{
  "1.2.3.4": [
    "domain1.com", "domain1-1.com"
  ],
  "1.2.3.5": [
    "domain2.com"
  ]
}
```

And I have tried the following model to only get `null`. Since the following didn't work, I broke the problem to just key-value pairs. To my surprise, the simple map also didn't work.

```
public class DnsLookup {
  @Getter @Setter private Map<String, List<String>> entry;
}
```

Am I doing a noob mistake?

Comment: By `null` in `dns`, I mean the `dns.getEntry()` is `null`

Comment: Thanks, @Qiu Zhou and @Axbor Axrorov.
For now, I have ended up using `Map<String, String>` and `Map<String, List<String>>`.
However, I am required to use models as much as possible. Perhaps do you know why the User-defined class method didn't work? 
I had been using JSON to POJO converter for complex JSON objects.

Comment: If you have to use DnsLookup as response body, then the returned JSON should be `{ "entry": { "1.2.3.4": "domain1.com", "1.2.3.5": "domain2.com" }}`, you see, your JSON missed `entry` as the key, if the returned JSON can't be changed, I am afraid you have to use Map.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@GET("/dns/")
Call<Map<String, List<String>>> getDns(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

Instead of:

```
@GET("/dns/")
Call<DnsLookup> getDns(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```